# What is the subject in "The gift Karen gave to her brother is a teddy bear"?

Tags: subjects, indirect-objects, subject-or-object

I am unable to ascertain what would be the *subject* in the following sentence.

> The gift Karen gave to her brother is a teddy bear.

Here the relative pronoun (that) has been omitted after the word *gift*. If I keep this in mind, then I can rewrite the sentence as

> Karen gave the gift to her brother. That gift is a teddy bear.

This gives *Karen* as a subject and *gift* as the object of the sentence.

Is this right?

Comment: The word *gift* is the subject, **that Karen gave to her brother** is an adjective clause modifying *gift*. Karen is the subject of the adjective clause.

Comment: No, because by changing the order of the words you change their function. The subject of the sentence is the noun phrase "The gift Karen gave to her brother", which contains the embedded relative clause "gave to her brother", which has "Karen" as subject. The relative clause is modifying "gift".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Barid Baran Acharya said, your last two sentences are a paraphrase; you cannot assume that they have the same grammatical structure as the first sentence.

Also, you have overlooked the fact that your paraphrase is *two* sentences.

The first sentence of your paraphrase "Karen gave the gift to her brother", has the subject "Karen" and the object "the gift", but the second sentence, "That gift is a teddy bear," has the subject "that gift".

The complex sentence you ask about in your question ("The gift Karen gave to her brother is a teddy bear") is closer in structure to the *second* sentence of your paraphrase. So the subject of "The gift Karen gave to her brother is a teddy bear" is the noun phrase "The gift Karen gave to her brother". It is not "Karen".

"Karen" is the subject of the embedded relative clause in the sentence: "Karen gave ___ to her brother". I have left a blank space there that corresponds to the direct object of the relative clause. The direct object of the relative clause is not explicitly present, but is understood to be the gift that is mentioned earlier in the sentence.

The main clause of the sentence "The gift Karen gave to her brother is a teddy bear" has no direct object. It is a copular sentence where the subject "The gift Karen gave to her brother" is described with the predicate noun phrase "a teddy bear", with the linking verb or auxiliary "is" used to connect the two (noun phrases cannot be used as predicates in English by themselves).

Comment: Sir, one more doubt came to my mind regarding this question. If I write it like "A teddy bear was the gift that Karen gave to her brother" will the subject change from the previous one to "a teddy bear" or will it be regarded as some kind of inversion?

Comment: @TheNOVICE: I think "A teddy bear" would be the subject in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In object pattern relative clauses the relative marker is omitted but that's not to mean that we are given the liberty of reorientation to the sentence structure. The fact remains that 'GIFT' is the subject of the sentence, it has a dependent relative clause without the relative marker and there is no object whatsoever. TEDDY BEAR is the subjective complement and "HER BROTHER" in the adjective clause is object of the preposition 'TO'. Your last two sentences are just mere paraphrase.

Comment: The content of this analysis looks reasonable. I wonder why it was voted down.

Comment: @Lawrence thanks a lot. Reason speaks to a mind that's ready to hear ; fortunately or unfortunately it is difficulty to get one as such.